# URL Shows Outdated Version of Template

Tags: templates, solspace-freeform, cache

I had a template and set the template cache to yes. Then a little while later I renamed it ".template-name" to hide it and renamed another template that I wanted to take it's place "template-name".

Now the URL displays the old template. The template is in the database not saved as a file.  I switched cache to no. I've deleted all the caches in EE and then deleted the subfolders from "cache" to no effect.

I've tried everything to get have the template update without any luck. I'm usingEE 2.6.1 and using Freeform 4.012

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: So I thought that there may be a conflict with ".template-name" and "template-name" because the of the "." so I changed it to ".template-name-backup" and it didn't fix the issue. to hide the template. After an hour I tried copying the new content into ".template-name-backup" and then it 'worked'. The "template-name" URL used the ".template-name-backup". So the template association was broken. Has anyone experienced this before? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried synchronizing the templates?

What is shown in the template editor within the CP?

Comment: Yup and nothing came on on Temp Sync probably because I don't store the templates as files?

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using? I know that Chrome tends to REALLY REALLY REALLY hang onto cached content, regardless of any server-side settings. Try looking at the template through a browser other than the one you normally use, and see if you can see your new/expected template. (I know it sounds like a basic n00b thing, but...dang if it hasn't caught me from time to time, and I've been doing this professionally for more than a decade.)

You might also try temporarily changing the name of ".template-name" to ".OLD-template-name" just to further let both the server and the browser know that Really, You Aren't Kidding, You Want To See That Updated Thing Now.